# Transform ip address to ip range (Start IP - End IP)

Tags: php

I am looking for a function that give me this result:

```
127.0.0.0-127.0.0.255
```

With only this ip:

```
127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.50 ...
```

Function will look like:

```
function transform_ip($ip) {
 // Method to transform ip the ip-range
 // Specify Start IP and End IP
 return $result;
}
echo transform_ip("127.0.0.66"); // result: 127.0.0.0-127.0.0.255
```

Comment: This problem is underconstrained - please elaborate on what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you come out with the `127.0.0.50`?

Comment: I just updated my question, you can see now. 127.0.0.50 is just an example.

Comment: It looks like you want a function that takes `a.b.c.d` and returns `a.b.c.0-a.b.c.255`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hundreds of ways to trim off everything after the last period. One way is to explode and implode without the last item...

```
$a = explode('.',$ip); // $a is each number without the periods
pop($a); // Pop off the last number
$ip = implode('.',$a); // Recombine with periods
```

Now, you can just return your string:

```
$result = "$ip.0-$ip.255";
```

Comment: what if mask is 255.255.255.253 for 192.168.0.1? :)

Comment: He didn't say he was looking at masks. He stated that he wanted the last octet to be replaced with 0 to 255. See the comments below the question.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make much sense because if you want to get real range of the IPs in the network you would need to give second parameter which is IP mask.

So when you have IP with class C it has mask 255.255.255.0 and ip 192.168.0.1

when you have IP and mask you can calculate broadcast address and network address. In this particualr case it would be:

Network 192.168.0.0 which is network adress and 192.168.0.255 which is broadcast address, the adress pool would be 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254

For example at following link you can find function how to do it

- [Calculate Netmask/Gateway from IP Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769747/calculate-netmask-gateway-from-ip-blocks)
- [How can I determine network and broadcast address from the IP address and subnet mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034878/how-can-i-determine-network-and-broadcast-address-from-the-ip-address-and-subnet)
- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers

Also there are functions that convert ip to number and number to ip:

- [ip2long](http://php.net/ip2long) converts ip string to number
- [long2ip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php) converts number to IPv4 string

Edit:

I've created library for calculations using math and bit operations

to use `composer require rpodwika/network-calculator`

https://github.com/rpodwika/network-calculator